# python replace word as per condition

Tags: python, regex, file, file-io

At standard input, I am providing the following file:

```
    #123     595739778       "neutral"       Won the match #getin
    #164     595730008       "neutral"      Good girl
```

data#2 looks like this:

```
    labels 1 0 -1
    -1 0.272653 0.139626 0.587721
    1 0.0977782 0.0748234 0.827398
```

I want to see if its -1 in the data#2 file then replace with negative, 1 then positive and 0 then neutral

Following are my issues:

1. start in data#2 file on 2nd line
2. I am facing trouble with replace. I want to replace like below but its showing a error tht it expects 1 more argument but I already have 2 arguments there.
3. If I do, something like below (notice the print statement):

   ```
   if binary == "-1":
     senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"negative")
   elif binary == "1":
     senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"positive")
   elif binary == "0":
     senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"neutral")
   print id, "\t", num, "\t", senti, "\t", sent
   ```

   but if I do(notice print) then it does not go in the 'if conditions':

   ```
   if binary == "-1":
      senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"negative")
   elif binary == "1":
      senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"positive")
   elif binary == "0":
      senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"neutral")
   ```

   print id, "\t", num, "\t", senti, "\t", sent

**How do I print then.**
     output that I got:
        #123     595739778       "neutral"       Won the match #getin
        #164     595730008       "neutral"       Good girl

```
 output expected (replace just replaces the negative, positive & neutral as per data# file:

    #123     595739778       negative       Won the match #getin
    #164     595730008       positive       Good girl
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./combine.py", line 17, in <module>
     senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"negative")
 TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here is my code:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    (id,num,senti,sent) = re.split("\t+",line.strip())
    tweet = re.split("\s+", sent.strip().lower())
    f = open("data#2.txt","r")
    for line1 in f:
       (binary,rest,rest1,test2) = re.split("\s", line1.strip())
       if binary == "-1":
          senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"negative")
       elif binary == "1":
          senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"positive")
       elif binary == "0":
          senti = str.replace(senti.strip('"'),"neutral")
       print id, "\t", num, "\t", senti, "\t", sent
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in fact missing an argument for replace; since it is a method of the string itself, you could do either:

```
In [72]: str.replace('one','o','1')
Out[72]: '1ne'
```

or

```
In [73]: 'one'.replace('o','1')
Out[73]: '1ne'
```

In your code, you likely want, e.g.

```
   if binary == "-1":
      senti = senti.strip('"').replace("-1","negative")
```

To skip the first line of your data#2 file, one option is

```
f = open("data#2.txt","r")
for line1 in f.readlines()[1:]: # skip the first line
   #rest of your code here
```

Edit: After a chat conversation, what I think you want is more like the following:

```
f = open("data#2.txt","r")
datalines = f.readlines()[1:]

count = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    if count == len(datalines): break # kill the loop if we've reached the end
    (tweetid,num,senti,tweets) = re.split("\t+",line.strip())
    tweet = re.split("\s+", tweets.strip().lower())
    # grab the right index from our list
    (binary,rest,rest1,test2) = re.split("\s", datalines[count].strip())
    if binary == "-1":
        sentiment = "negative"
    elif binary == "1":
        sentiment = "positive"
    elif binary == "0":
        sentiment = "neutral"
    print tweetid, "\t", num, "\t", sentiment, "\t", tweets
    count += 1 # add to our counter
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say here. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: What output are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Again, you posted the output you're expecting but not what you are actually getting. I can't help if you don't provide enough information.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42822/discussion-between-fscore-and-qmorgan)